# How to store UUIDs client side

Tags: java, database, uuid

For my app I have a server-side database in which I store users and their data. I am wondering how to keep track of which user has which UUID. I want to make sure that only the same user with their own unique UUID can access their data in the database.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you put the UUID on the same database table the user is on?

Comment: In continuing @ZackMacomber's suggestion, you can use `UUID()` on many RDBMS to generate a random UUID for a user by default.

Comment: Yes i can, however i did not properly word my question as i was more looking for a way of making sure whenever a user starts the app they get their personal data from the database without a login system, so something like storing the UUID on the users computer

Answer (score 0):

In your database, create a table where each row represents one particular user. That table would have their permanently assigned UUID, along with name, email, etc.

Some databases such as Postgres and [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) support UUID as a built-in data type. Some databases proved a feature, perhaps as a plug-in, to generate a UUID value. For example, the [*uuid-ossp*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) plug-in for Postgres. If not, you can generate a UUID in Java.

When creating an account for a user, create a row in that table. When a user logs in, look up their credentials in this table, retrieving their previously assigned UUID.

During the execution of your app, keep that retrieved UUID in memory as a [`java.util.UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) object. In a web app built on Jakarta Servlet, a good place to keep their UUID would be as an attribute on the Session. See [*Binding Attributes into a Session*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/jakarta-servlet-spec-5.0.html#binding-attributes-into-a-session) in the spec. See [`HttpSession#setAttribute`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpsession#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)) and [`getAttribute`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpsession#getAttribute(java.lang.String)).

When you write rows in other tables that belong to a particular user, include a column for their UUID. Include their UUID as a criteria in your queries.

You might want to look into [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) as a topic.

Answer (score 0):

After authenticating the user (via your favorite authentication process), add a `set-cookie` response header with the user id (or any other data you deem appropriate) as the value.

Don't forget to set the cookie properties httponly, secure, and samesite.